# Canonical filtration of piecewise constant process is right-continuous

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, stochastic-processes, filtrations

I am facing the following statement:

Let $L$ be a piecewise constant stochastic process and let $(\mathfrak{F}_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ be the completed filtration generetad by $L$.
Then the usual conditions are satisfied.

The usual conditions here mean that the filtration is right-continuous and that $\mathfrak{F}_0$ contains all nullsets.

That $\mathfrak{F}_0$ contains all nullsets follows from the choice of the completed filtration.
But how do I show that the filtration is right-continuous?

Right continuity means that
$$
\mathfrak{F}_t = \bigcap_{s > t} \mathfrak{F}_s
$$
is satisfied.

Comment: Pls refer to the book: Philip E. Protter, *Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations*, 2nd Ed, Springer-Verlag, 2005.  Th.1.25, p.16.

Comment: It seems that this theorem is stated where $L$ is a counting process. Would we be able to deduce the right-continuity by representing $L$ as the difference of two counting processes?

Comment: To give more context, the process $L$ is part of the so called first jump approximation. The statement is in the proof of Theorem 3.5 of the following paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.spa.2008.09.008

Comment: For the Protter reference I would rather go for theorem 31 Section 1,which states that a Lévy process under completed filtration has right continuous filtration, so if $L$ is Lévy process (as your comment above suggest) the answer is clearly lies in the proof of this theorem.regards

Comment: In fact, using the method in Protter's book could prove the statment: The complete natural filtration of a piecewise constant stochastic process(a right continuous stepwise process) is right continuous, the key is that for each $ \omega $, there exists an $ n $ such that 
$ s\mapsto N_s(\omega) $ is constant on $ [t,t+\frac1n] $.